# Decorator for multiple interfaces - a circular dependency riddle in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac, circular-dependency

I'm coming from Ninject but I decided to give Autofac a try since it seems more actively developed. So far I can say that registering decorators is not as easy as in Ninject using `.WhenInjectedExactlyInto` syntax. Anyway please bear with me as I am an Autofac newbie.

Here's the problem:

I have type `A` implementing interface `IA` that is decorated by `A_Decorator`. `A_Decorator` implements interfaces `IA` and `IB`, and in turn should be decorated by `AB_Decorator` that also implements both `IA` and `IB`. `AB_Decorator` takes two dependencies of types `IA` and `IB` (so it is a decorator for both) but they both should resolve to the same instance of `A_Decorator`. It looks something like this: `AB_Decorator(A_Decorator(A) as IA, A_Decorator(A) as IB)`. When requesting service of type `IA` or type `IB` from Autofac container, they should reference a single `AB_Decorator` instance.

It is a bit tricky to describe by word, but here's the simplest code sample I could come up with that shows this situation (I've added instance IDs and trace messages to constructors to see what's going on):

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace AutofacExample
{
    internal interface IA { }

    internal interface IB { }

    class A : IA
    {
        static int _instanceCounter;
        readonly int Id = ++_instanceCounter;

        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{GetType().Name}[{nameof(Id)}={Id}]";
        }
    }

    class A_Decorator : IA, IB
    {
        static int _instanceCounter = 10;
        readonly int Id = ++_instanceCounter;

        /* decorated1 should reference instance of A */

        public A_Decorator(IA decoratedA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{this}({nameof(decoratedA)}={decoratedA})");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{GetType().Name}[{nameof(Id)}={Id}]";
        }
    }

    class AB_Decorator : IA, IB
    {
        static int _instanceCounter = 100;
        readonly int Id = ++_instanceCounter;

        /* Both decorated1 and decorated2 should reference the same instance of A_Decorator */

        public AB_Decorator(IA decoratedA, IB decoratedB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{this}({nameof(decoratedA)}={decoratedA}, {nameof(decoratedB)}={decoratedB})");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{GetType().Name}[{nameof(Id)}={Id}]";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder
                .RegisterType<A>()
                .Named<IA>(nameof(A))
                .SingleInstance();

            builder
                .RegisterType<A_Decorator>()
                .Named<IA>(nameof(A_Decorator))
                .Named<IB>(nameof(A_Decorator))
                .SingleInstance();

            builder
                .RegisterType<AB_Decorator>()
                .Named<IA>(nameof(AB_Decorator))
                .Named<IB>(nameof(AB_Decorator))
                .SingleInstance();

            /* A is decorated by A_Decorator as IA */
            builder
                .RegisterDecorator<IA>(
                    (c, decorated) =>
                        c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(A_Decorator), TypedParameter.From(decorated)),
                    nameof(A))
                //.Keyed<IA>("innerA")
                //.Keyed<IB>("innerB")
                .SingleInstance();

            /* Trying to register AB_Decorator as IA creates circular dependency */
            //builder
            //    .RegisterDecorator<IA>(
            //        (c, decorated) =>
            //            c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(AB_Decorator), TypedParameter.From(decorated)),
            //        "innerA")
            //    .SingleInstance();

            /* A_Decorator is decorated by AB_Decorator as IB */
            builder
                .RegisterDecorator<IB>(
                        (c, decorated) =>
                            c.ResolveNamed<IB>(nameof(AB_Decorator), TypedParameter.From(decorated)),
                        nameof(A_Decorator) /* "innerB" */)
                    .SingleInstance();

            IContainer container = builder.Build();

            IA a = container.Resolve<IA>();
            IB b = container.Resolve<IB>();

            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(a)} == {nameof(b)} ? {ReferenceEquals(a, b)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(a)} is {a.GetType().Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(b)} is {b.GetType().Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately requesting instance of `IA` gives me `A_Decorator`, while for `IB` I get `AB_Decorator`. Trying to uncomment the extra decorator registration block causes circular dependency exception (`DependencyResolutionException: Circular component dependency detected: System.Object -> AutofacExample.AB_Decorator -> System.Object -> AutofacExample.AB_Decorator`) and I can't make it work trying various combinations of the named registrations.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem lies with the decorator registrations for `AB_Decorator`. Specifically the lambda function resolving the `AB_Decorator`:

```
( c, decorated ) => c.ResolveNamed<IA>( nameof( AB_Decorator ), TypedParameter.From( decorated ) );
```

The constructor for `AB_Decorator` takes in 2 arguments that should both be the same instance of `A_Decorator` which is being supplied to the lambda as `decorated`. However, `decorated` is being passed as a parameter only once via `TypedParameter.From( decorated )`. Therefore Autofac is going to try to resolve the second parameter via the container.

Now the registrations for `IB` show that we should get a singleton instance with `A_Decorator` wrapped in `AB_Decorator`. So to resolve `IB`, the container must construct `AB_Decorator`. There's the problem, we're currently trying to resolve `AB_Decorator` as `IA`, but we need an `IB` to fulfill the constructor arguments for the `AB_Decorator` being constructed for `IA`. And `IB` is registered in the container as `AB_Decorator`. So you get:

```
AB_Decorator(A_Decorator(A) as IA, AB_Decorator(A_Decorator(A) as IA, AB_Decorator(etc...))
```

#### Solution

We need to pass `decorated` into both parameters when resolving `AB_Decorator`. Like this:

```
builder
    .RegisterDecorator<IA>(
        ( c, decorated ) =>

            c.ResolveNamed<IA>( nameof( AB_Decorator ),
                new TypedParameter( typeof( IA ), decorated ),
                new TypedParameter( typeof( IB ), decorated )
            )
        ,"innerA"
    )
    .SingleInstance();


builder
    .RegisterDecorator<IB>(
        ( c, decorated ) =>

            c.ResolveNamed<IB>( nameof( AB_Decorator ),
                new TypedParameter( typeof( IA ), decorated ),
                new TypedParameter( typeof( IB ), decorated )
            )
        , nameof( A_Decorator ) /* "innerB" */
    )
    .SingleInstance();
```

Now we are sending `decorated` which is `A_Decorator` to both the `IA` and the `IB` parameters. Directly constructing the `TypedParameter` instances allows me to specify the type I want the instance to fulfill in the parameters list for, in this case, `AB_Decorator`.

Comment: It works thank you. Your solution produces more code than Nicholas Blumhardt's below (requires 3 RegisterDecorator blocks), but it is more explicit about usage of decorators, which is nice. :) I am accepting this one as it is also a bit better explained.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder
    .RegisterType<A>()
    .Named<IA>(nameof(A))
    .SingleInstance();

builder
    .RegisterType<A_Decorator>()
    .Named<IA>(nameof(A_Decorator))
    .Named<IB>(nameof(A_Decorator))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedA", 
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(A))))
    .SingleInstance();

builder
    .RegisterType<AB_Decorator>()
    .As<IA, IB>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedA",
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(A_Decorator))))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedB",
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IB>(nameof(A_Decorator))))
    .SingleInstance();

IContainer container = builder.Build();
```

Prints:

```
A[Id=1]
A_Decorator[Id=11](decoratedA=A[Id=1])
AB_Decorator[Id=101](decoratedA=A_Decorator[Id=11], decoratedB=A_Decorator[Id=11])
a == b ? True
a is AB_Decorator
b is AB_Decorator
```

The API is confusing, because you don't need `RegisterDecorator()` in this scenario (it's for decorating a whole set of components at once).

(It would be nice if we could bake the whole:

```
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedA", 
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(A))))
```

idiom down into a simpler `WithParameter()` overload in Autofac; I think this'd be a good suggestion to raise on the project's issue tracker if you see the win here.)

Comment: This one also works and the code is actually shorter. I accepted the other answer because it is more explicit about decorator usage and has a tad more explanation, even though I ended up using yours to cut down on code lines - hope you don't mind :). Also I definitely think it's worth simplifying the decorator API in Autofac, so please feel free to use this question if you decide to raise the suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: One extra point: in case where constructor parameters have unique types (as is in this case) I ended up using `new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IA), (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IA>(nameof(A)))` to identify parameters by their type instead of name - leaves less room for a refactoring trap. :)